# Swift UICollectionView Cell displayed/scrolled in to the view incorrectly when keyboard hiding animation change bottom inset

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am building a messanger view in iOs (Swift) app with help of UICollectionView inside a UIViewController. I am taking inspiration from MessageKit and I was able to set everything properly with simple dynamic cell height. When I hide the keyboard and the collection view bottom inset is reduced while the collection view is scrolled to bottom, it logically drags cells in to the view from top (scrolls down). I am not sure if it is somehow in conflict with keyboard hiding animation, but if this cause the collection view scroll to much and therefore display cells that have not been in the view, they appear not as scrolled in, but with some strange layout animation. It happens only while hiding keyboard && collectionView is at the bottom. Please check the gif:

[link to gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QljXB.gif)

Building everything on UITableView did work, but I aim for collection view due to future features. I tried to use even a fixed cell height in a CollectionViewFlowDelegate, but it has the same effect as dynamically calculated heights.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

I am setting the UICollectionView inset the same way as in the MessageKit:

```swift
    private func requiredScrollViewBottomInset(forKeyboardFrame keyboardFrame: CGRect) -> CGFloat {
        let intersection = chatCollectionView.frame.intersection(keyboardFrame)
        if intersection.isNull || (chatCollectionView.frame.maxY - intersection.maxY) > 0.001 {
        messagesCollectionView.frame.maxY when dealing with undocked keyboards.
            return max(0, additionalBottomInset - automaticallyAddedBottomInset)
        } else {
            return max(0, intersection.height + additionalBottomInset - automaticallyAddedBottomInset)
        }
    }

    @objc private func handleKeyboardDidChangeState(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard !isMessagesControllerBeingDismissed else { return }
        guard let keyboardStartFrameInScreenCoords = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else { return }
        guard !keyboardStartFrameInScreenCoords.isEmpty || UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom != .pad else {
            // WORKAROUND for what seems to be a bug in iPad's keyboard handling in iOS 11: we receive an extra spurious frame change
            // notification when undocking the keyboard, with a zero starting frame and an incorrect end frame. The workaround is to
            // ignore this notification.
            return
        }
        guard let keyboardEndFrameInScreenCoords = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else { return }
        let keyboardEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardEndFrameInScreenCoords, from: view.window)
        let newBottomInset = requiredScrollViewBottomInset(forKeyboardFrame: keyboardEndFrame)
        let differenceOfBottomInset = newBottomInset - messageCollectionViewBottomInset
        if maintainPositionOnKeyboardFrameChanged && differenceOfBottomInset >/*!=*/ 0 {
            let contentOffset = CGPoint(x: chatCollectionView.contentOffset.x, y: chatCollectionView.contentOffset.y + differenceOfBottomInset)
            chatCollectionView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
        }
        messageCollectionViewBottomInset = newBottomInset
    }

    internal func requiredInitialScrollViewBottomInset() -> CGFloat {
        print("accessory view for initial bottom inset: \(inputAccessoryView)")
        guard let inputAccessoryView = inputAccessoryView else { return 0 }
        return max(0, inputAccessoryView.frame.height + additionalBottomInset - automaticallyAddedBottomInset)
    }
```

As I could not find any related topic regarding this scrolling upon keyboard hiding, I am not sure if this is reusableCell issue or animation conflict?

**EDIT**

So the partial solution is to invalidate layout only if the width change, this will prevent keyboard invalidating it while hiding:

```swift
open override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return collectionView?.bounds.width != newBounds.width
    }
```

But it also prevents sticky headers to get invalidated and therefore resign being sticky. I went deeper into invalidationContext as this looked as potential full solution, although I get the same behaviour.

```swift
open override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        invalidateLayout(with: invalidationContext(forBoundsChange: newBounds))
        return collectionView?.bounds.width != newBounds.width
    }

    open override func invalidationContext(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext {
        let context = super.invalidationContext(forBoundsChange: newBounds)
        guard let flowLayoutContext = context as? UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext else { return context }
        let indexes: [IndexPath] = (collectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleSupplementaryElements(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader))!
        print(indexes)
        flowLayoutContext.invalidateSupplementaryElements(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: indexes)
        print(context.invalidatedSupplementaryIndexPaths)
        return flowLayoutContext
    }
```

Print statements clearly state that only headers are invalidated, and for the rest I am returning false. But it behaves exactly the same as in the gif (see the link - unfortunately I have reputation not high enough yet to add it directly here). Thank you for any comments!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After long investigation I noticed that the same phenomen happens also at the bottom in particular cases. I am not sure it it is bug or custom layout is necessary, but with the simple flow layout I solved the issue by setting collectionView contraints beyound the display edge.

This force to call displaying cell earlier and gives some time to lay cell approprietely even hide keyboard animation is used. Of coarse collectionView top and bottom contentInset has to be set in viewDidLoad and handle any contentInset change during runtime accordingly

Hope it help!

EDIT:

I ended up using CADisplaLink for scrolling of the collectionView when the keyboard shows and setting the bottom inset without animation. This case the inset to change exactly in the moment, when scroll function is scrolling the collection, so there is no jump and each frame has correct layout. For the keyboard hide it is quite simple - setting bottom inset in keyboardWillHide cause the collection to adjust offset upon releasing the finger also outside animation block and therefore is the layout also correct.

Following code is inspired by multiple answers here and by MessakeKit on GitHub

```
let scrollController = ScrollController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    scrollController.scrollView = self.chatCollectionView
    scrollController.decelerationAllowed = true
    scrollController.keepUserInteractionDuringScroll = true        
}

@objc private func keyboardWillShowOrHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard !ignoreKeyboardNotification, !insertingMessage, !isViewControllerBeingDismissed, viewAlreadyAppeared else { return }
    guard let keyboardEndFrameInScreenCoords = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else { return }
    let keyboardEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardEndFrameInScreenCoords, from: view.window)
    let newBottomInset = requiredScrollViewBottomInset(forKeyboardFrame: keyboardEndFrame)
    let deltaBottomInset = newBottomInset - messageCollectionViewBottomInset
    let differenceOfBottomInset = min(deltaBottomInset, collectionViewContentHightIntersectSafeArea())
    ignoreScrollButtonHide = true
    let scrollButtonOriginY = keyboardEndFrameInScreenCoords.origin.y - (self.scrollToBottomButtonMargin + self.scrollButton.frame.size.height)
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        let contentOffset = chatCollectionView.contentOffset
        self.messageCollectionViewBottomInset = newBottomInset
        self.chatCollectionView.contentOffset = contentOffset
    }
    if !chatCollectionView.isTracking {
        if differenceOfBottomInset != 0 {
            let beginOffsetY = self.scrollController.endContentOffset == CGPoint.zero ? self.chatCollectionView.contentOffset.y : self.scrollController.endContentOffset.y
            let negativeScroll = differenceOfBottomInset < 0//if difference is negative, it should not scroll pass the topScrollOffset
            let setContentOffsetY = negativeScroll ? max(beginOffsetY + differenceOfBottomInset, topScrollOffset()) : beginOffsetY + differenceOfBottomInset
            let contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: setContentOffsetY)
            self.scrollController.setContentOffset(contentOffset, with: .easeOut, duration: self.animationsDuration)
        }
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut, .allowAnimatedContent, .overrideInheritedOptions, .beginFromCurrentState], animations: {
        self.chatCollectionView.verticalScrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = newBottomInset
        self.scrollButton.frame.origin.y = scrollButtonOriginY
        self.adjustLangSelectionViews()
    }, completion: { (complete) in
        self.ignoreScrollButtonHide = false
        if self.chatCollectionView.isDecelerating == false { //do not hide if still scrolling
            self.pinnedHeaderIsHidden(hidden: true)
        }
    })        
}
```

I unfortunately did not saved, where I got the scrollController code for the CADisplayLink. If author could contact me, Iĺl be more than happy to put the link to the source here.

```
class ScrollController {

//CADisplayLink
private let scrollAnimationDuration: TimeInterval = 0.25
private let scrollApproximationTolerance: Double = 0.00000001
private let scrollMaximumSteps: Int = 10
var displayLink: CADisplayLink? // Display link used to trigger event to scroll the view
private var timingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction? // Timing function of an scroll animation
private var duration: CFTimeInterval = 0 // Duration of an scroll animation
private var animationStarted = false // States whether the animation has started
private var beginTime: CFTimeInterval = 0 // Time at the begining of an animation
private var beginContentOffset = CGPoint.zero // The content offset at the begining of an animation
private var deltaContentOffset = CGPoint.zero // The delta between the scroll contentOffsets
var endContentOffset = CGPoint.zero // The delta between the scroll contentOffsets

var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var keepUserInteractionDuringScroll = false
var delegateClass: UIScrollViewDelegate?
var decelerationAllowed: Bool = false
    
func setContentOffset(_ contentOffset: CGPoint, with timingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction?, duration: CFTimeInterval, deceleratingAllowed: Bool? = false) {
    self.duration = duration
    self.timingFunction = timingFunction
    
    deltaContentOffset = CGPointMinus(contentOffset, scrollView.contentOffset)
    endContentOffset = contentOffset
    decelerationAllowed = deceleratingAllowed!
    
    if displayLink == nil {
        displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(updateContentOffset(_:)))
        displayLink?.add(to: .main, forMode: .common)
        scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = keepUserInteractionDuringScroll
    } else {
        beginTime = 0.0
    }
}

@objc func updateContentOffset(_ displayLink: CADisplayLink?) {
    if beginTime == 0.0 {
        beginTime = self.displayLink?.timestamp ?? 0
        beginContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    } else {
        let deltaTime = (displayLink?.timestamp ?? 0) - beginTime
        // Ratio of duration that went by
        let progress = CGFloat(deltaTime / duration)
        if progress < 1.0 {
            // Ratio adjusted by timing function
            let adjustedProgress = CGFloat(timingFunctionValue(timingFunction, Double(progress)))
            if 1 - adjustedProgress < 0.001 {
                stopDisplayLink()
            } else {
                updateProgress(adjustedProgress)
            }
        } else {
            stopDisplayLink()
        }
    }
}

func updateProgress(_ progress: CGFloat) {
    let currentDeltaContentOffset = CGPointScalarMult(progress, deltaContentOffset)
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointAdd(beginContentOffset, currentDeltaContentOffset)
}

func stopDisplayLink() {
    displayLink?.isPaused = true
    beginTime = 0.0
    if !decelerationAllowed {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(endContentOffset, animated: false)
    } else {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointAdd(beginContentOffset, deltaContentOffset)
    }
    endContentOffset = CGPoint.zero
    displayLink?.invalidate()
    displayLink = nil
    scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    if delegateClass != nil {
        delegateClass!.scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation?(scrollView)
    }
}

func CGPointScalarMult(_ s: CGFloat, _ p: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: s * p.x, y: s * p.y)
}


func CGPointAdd(_ p: CGPoint, _ q: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: p.x + q.x, y: p.y + q.y)
}


func CGPointMinus(_ p: CGPoint, _ q: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: p.x - q.x, y: p.y - q.y)
}


func cubicFunctionValue(_ a: Double, _ b: Double, _ c: Double, _ d: Double, _ x: Double) -> Double {
    return (a*x*x*x)+(b*x*x)+(c*x)+d//Double(d as? c as? b as? a ?? 0.0)
}


func cubicDerivativeValue(_ a: Double, _ b: Double, _ c: Double, _ d: Double, _ x: Double) -> Double {
    /// Derivation of the cubic (a*x*x*x)+(b*x*x)+(c*x)+d
    return (3 * a * x * x) + (2 * b * x) + c
}


func rootOfCubic(_ a: Double, _ b: Double, _ c: Double, _ d: Double, _ startPoint: Double) -> Double {
    // We use 0 as start point as the root will be in the interval [0,1]
    var x = startPoint
    var lastX: Double = 1

    // Approximate a root by using the Newton-Raphson method
    var y = 0
    while y <= scrollMaximumSteps && fabs(lastX - x/*Float(lastX - x)*/) > scrollApproximationTolerance {
        lastX = x
        x = x - (cubicFunctionValue(a, b, c, d, x) / cubicDerivativeValue(a, b, c, d, x))
        y += 1
    }

    return x
}


func timingFunctionValue(_ function: CAMediaTimingFunction?, _ x: Double) -> Double {
    var a = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: 2)
    var b = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: 2)
    var c = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: 2)
    var d = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: 2)

    function?.getControlPoint(at: 0, values: &a)
    function?.getControlPoint(at: 1, values: &b)
    function?.getControlPoint(at: 2, values: &c)
    function?.getControlPoint(at: 3, values: &d)

    // Look for t value that corresponds to provided x
    let t = rootOfCubic(Double(-a[0] + 3 * b[0] - 3 * c[0] + d[0]), Double(3 * a[0] - 6 * b[0] + 3 * c[0]), Double(-3 * a[0] + 3 * b[0]), Double(a[0]) - x, x)

    // Return corresponding y value
    let y = cubicFunctionValue(Double(-a[1] + 3 * b[1] - 3 * c[1] + d[1]), Double(3 * a[1] - 6 * b[1] + 3 * c[1]), Double(-3 * a[1] + 3 * b[1]), Double(a[1]), t)

    return y
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, do you happen to find any solution now?

Comment: Please, see the edited answer. Let me know if anything is unclear